# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - Python/Django Locallibrary

Tags: python, django

So I'm following this tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page

Using this code in my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]
```

Throws me the error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jakoubu/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog/urls.py'
```

Anyone knows what's up? I've searched the entire internet for answers...

Comment: What are the permissions of the file, and is the user running Django allowed to read it?

Comment: How do you start your application? Does your user have read access to `urls.py`? Try this: `stat -c %G:%A /home/jakoubu/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog/urls.py`

Comment: @GeorgyKomarov That command returns: jakoubu:----------

Comment: @Sun `sudo chmod 655 /home/jakoubu/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog/urls.py`

Comment: @GeorgyKomarov This worked! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like whatever user is running the Django server is doesn't have access to the urls.py file.

To see who owns the file, use the `ls -l /home/jakoubu/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog` command and see the username in the third column of that file.

The other important thing to note from that command is the first column, which describes who is allowed to access those files. You'll see 10 letters for each file and the output might look like this:

`drwxr-xr-x`

The way to read this is:

first character: is it a directory? `d` if yes, `-` if no

next 3 characters: what permissions does the file owner have? `rwx` is short for "read, write, and execute". If any of these are missing, the owner can't do that operation. (use `whoami` to see which user you are)

next 3 characters: what permissions does the "group" have? Similar to the one above, but for a group of users instead. (use `groups` to see which groups you belong to)

last 3 characters: what permissions does everybody else have?

**Heavy handed solution, sure to solve your problem**: let anybody on your computer access that file `chmod 777 /home/jakoubu/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog/urls.py`. This will definitely work, but there's a deeper problem of ownership of your files that you should use the commands above to investigate and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem permissions are incorrect. Check your file permissions if it's readable for the user your webserver is using.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PermissionError

Comment: How do I give myself full permission? It's running locally.